# Inverse Bits of an Integer using C#

Tags: c#, byte, reverse, mask, bit

I wanted to ask if there is an efficient way to inverse all set and unset bits in an integer.
For example:
If I have the integer:

`1338842`

this is the same in binary as this:

```
101000110110111011010
```

How can I inverse this so every 1 bit becomes a 0 bit and every 0 bit becomes a 1 bit.
The reversed result then should be:

```
010111001001000100101
```

which is basically the integer:

```
758309
```

Unfortunately I can't show my attempt because I don't have any.
I don't know how to do this.
Thats why I hope someone from the board can give me some advice.

Answer (score 10):

This is exactly what the bitwise not operator (`~`) does.

Answer (score 7):

bitwise operators!

```
int value = 1338842;
int inversed = ~value;
```